# Wireless not working after installing Windows updates

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a Compaq laptop. The wireless on it was working fine until some Windows updates got installed and my wireless stopped functioning.

### EDIT

The wireless router is working fine as I am able to connect to it using my android phone

Device Manager >> Network Devices -- I see my LAN alone listed

I see a device that has an exclamtion mark.

When I do a `ipconfig` I get something new called

> Tunnel adapter teredo Tunneling psuedo interface

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried doing a system restore from before the updates?

Comment: We don't know what your wireless device is either, how about some hints? :)  What's 'not working' about it?  What have you tried (beyond IPConfig)?

Comment: Problem descriptions like "not working" are not helpful. Can you get the list of detected wireless networks? Is yours on it? If so, what happens when you double-click on it? You have to give us something to go on.

Answer (score 1):

visit the Compaq/HP site and download the proper driver and re-install.  That may address the issue.  Using model info, it should be easy to find the needed driver(s)

In the Device manager are there any devices with Exclamation marks.